# Cannot compile moderncv class document when using tinytex in RStudio

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, tinytex

I am unable to compile an Rmd file using tinytex via RStudio. I can compile the same file without issues on another computer that has a full LaTeX installation.

I have written my CV using the `moderncv` class in RMarkdown. I have a full LaTeX distribution installed on one of my computers and I can compile the CV without any problems. On my new computer I have installed TinyTex via the r package `tinytex` and use it to compile Rmd files to pdf via RStudio. For some reason I cannot compile the same document on my new computer when using tinytex. I have tried manually installing all of the packages I load in my preamble without luck. My preliminary searches have not uncovered in problems similar to this one. I am using the [kjh-vita](https://github.com/kjhealy/kjh-vita) template provided by Kieran Healy, though it has been modified to work with Rmd.

I've noticed that if I set the `keep_tex` YAML argument to `yes` that the .tex file that is produced is escaping out all of the curly braces (see image). The green portion is how it should look (i.e., how it looks in my .Rmd file) and the red portion is what is produced in the .tex file after knitting the document.

[image: tinytex changes]

I believe the solution to my problem involves getting tinytex to stop escaping all of the curly braces in the file. I have no idea why this is happening or how to get it to stop.

**update**: add minimal working example

```
% Basic preamble
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{moderncv}

% Pull from header includes


% moderncv themes
\moderncvtheme[black]{classic} % optional argument are 'blue' (default), 
                               % 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 
                               % 'grey' and 'roman' (for roman fonts, 
                               % instead of sans serif fonts)
%\usepackage{assets/tex/moderncvthemeclassic}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %character encoding

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url,fancyhdr}

% needed for xelatex to work
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% my additions: 
% include ipa and bib formatting
\let\sups\relax
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[spanish, english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\newcommand{\bibverse}[1]{\begin{verse} \bibentry{#1}. \end{verse}}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{academicons}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}

%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}           % if you want to change the 
                                              % width of the column with the 
                                              % dates
%\setlength{\maketitlenamewidth}{10cm}}       % only for the classic theme, 
                                              % if you want to change the 
                                              % width of your name placeholder 
                                              % (to leave more space for your 
                                              % address details




% Personal data
\firstname{Person}
\familyname{Name}
\title{Assistant Professor}
\address{Some University \\ 
         Department of Stuff}{City, State 08401}
% \mobile{}
\phone{(456) 921-6345}
%\fax{(456) 921-6345}
\email{anemail@mail.edu}
\homepage{www.page.com}
% \extrainfo{}
\def\mytitle{Professor}
\def\myphone{(456) 921-6345}
\def\myskype{myskype}
\def\myemail{jmymail@mail.edu}
\def\myweb{www.page.com}
\def\facweb{https://www.page.com}
\def\school{Some University}
\def\schoolweb{http://www.page.edu}


%\nopagenumbers{}  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs 
                   % longer than one page



\begin{document}

\bigskip

\vspace{.1in}

\noindent{\huge {\textsc{My Name}, Ph.D.}}
\reversemarginpar

\noindent 

\rule{492pt}{1.5pt}
\vspace{-0.1in}

\begin{minipage}[t]{2.4in}
 \flushleft 
  \href{\schoolweb}{\school} \\ 
  My buildin \\  
  15 Street place \\
  Street, \textsc{State} 08305 
\end{minipage}
\hfill     
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.7in}
  \flushleft 
  \faUniversity \phantom{-}\href{\facweb}{Faculty page} \\
  \faPhone \phantom{-}\myphone \\
  \faPaperPlane \phantom{-}\href{\myemail}{\texttt{\myemail}} \\
  \faHome \phantom{-}\href{https://www.page.com}{\texttt{\myweb}} \\
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.7in}
  \flushright 
  Google scholar: \href{http://www.page.com}{\aiGoogleScholar} \\ 
  ResearchGate: \href{http://www.page.com}{\aiResearchGate} \\
  @jvcasillas \href{https://www.github.com/}{\faGithub} \\ 
  @jvcasill \href{https://www.twitter.com/}{\faTwitter}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.1in}

\section{Appointments}

\cventry{2016 -- Present}
        {\mytitle}
        {Some University, Place}
        {}
        {}
        {Name of program, 
        Department of stuff}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Note that the translation from Rmd to tex is not done by TinyTeX but by knitr and pandoc.

Comment: It is difficult to see how MRE will be helpful, as the file can be knitted depending on the system (complete LaTeX distribution vs. tinytex). In any case I have included the minimal amount of code I can get to compile on the system with the complete LaTeX distribution.

Comment: I compiled your latex code above into a pdf with the code `tinytex::xelatex("tinytex-question.tex")` - where tinytex-question.tex contains exactly the latex code that you shared. Are you writing in markdown? or latex?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This makes me think it has to be pandoc. I am going to downgrade and see if I can compile.

Answer (score 1):

After pandoc version 2.5 the `\cventry{}` lines are not correctly parsed into latex. Specifically, this was what was causing the problems:

```
\cventry{2016 -- Present}
        {\mytitle}
        {Some University, Place}
        {}
        {}
        {Name of program, 
        Department of stuff}
```

I can knit the document that contains the above code with pandoc 2.5. Any version above 2.5 must be written as follows:

```
\cventry{2016 -- Present}{\mytitle}{Some University, Place}{}{}{Name of program, Department of stuff}
```

Pandoc inserts an escape character `\{\}` whenever there is blank space (as seen in the image above).